# OnFocus javascript command causing Wordpress to crash

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, onfocus

I'm tweaking a Wordpress theme and I'm trying to clear the search field on focus, but when I add the following code, I get the white screen of death. The actual javascript function seems to be what's killing it because if I run this PHP script with an empty onfocus="" command, everything is fine.

```
    add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_search_box', 10, 2);
    function add_search_box($items, $args) {
if( $args->theme_location == 'primary' ) {
    $items .= '<li id="omc-header-search">              
                    <span id="omc-search-overlay">'. __('Search', 'gonzo') .' &rarr;</span>
                    <form method="get" id="desktop-search" class="omc-search-form" action="'.get_bloginfo('url').'/">
                        <input type="text" class="omc-header-search-input-box" value="Search" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Default text') { this.value = ''; }" name="s" id="fffff">
                        <input type="submit" class="omc-header-search-button" id="searchsubmit" value="">
                    </form>
                </li>';

return $items;

}
```

I have no idea why this would be causing the whole thing to crash.

Comment: Add this to your php, for debugging. Then you see more info about errors: `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); ini_set("display_errors", 1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A white page usually indicates a PHP fatal error or syntax error.
In this case, there's a couple different errors:

- You have not closed the `{` from your `if()` statement
- Your long string of text has embedded quotes `'` that are not properly escaped.

You're also inconsistant in what the default text in the field should be.

- You're setting it to `"Search"` with `value="Search"`
- ...but you're clearing it only if it equals `"Default text"`.

If you fix the PHP syntax errors, and update `Default text` to `Search`, it should work.

Like this:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_search_box', 10, 2);
function add_search_box($items, $args) {
    if( $args->theme_location == 'primary' ) {
        $items .= '<li id="omc-header-search">              
            <span id="omc-search-overlay">'. __('Search', 'gonzo') .' &rarr;</span>
            <form method="get" id="desktop-search" class="omc-search-form" action="'.get_bloginfo('url').'/">
            <input type="text" class="omc-header-search-input-box" value="Search" onfocus="if(this.value == \'Search\') { this.value = \'\'; }" name="s" id="fffff">
            <input type="submit" class="omc-header-search-button" id="searchsubmit" value="">
            </form>
            </li>';
    }
    return $items;
}
```

Comment: Okay, it's no longer causing a fatal error, but the field is not clearing on focus. <input type="text" class="omc-header-search-input-box" value="Search" onfocus="if(this.value == \"Default text\"") { this.value = \"\"; }" name="s" id="fffff">

Comment: @thebeat42 Don't change from single to double-quotes - that'll mess up the generated HTML. single-quotes are good as long as you escape them in PHP. Also, did you try updating `"Default text"` to `"Search"`? Check the (updated) second part of my answer.

Comment: @thebeat42 See my updated answer with (should-be-working) code.

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the quotes inside the `onfocus`:

```
onfocus="if(this.value == \'Default text\') { this.value = \'\'; }"
```

When echoed by php the backslash will disappear and the script will look like you want.

Comment: Well that doesn't crash it, but it's not clearing the field on focus.

Comment: @thebeat42, I just corrected my answer to double-quotes. How does the script look in the source code after rendering?

Comment: This is how it renders, and it shows up red: <input type="text" class="omc-header-search-input-box" value="Search" onfocus="if(this.value == \"Default text\"") { this.value = \"\"; }" name="s" id="fffff">

Comment: `onfocus="if(this.value == \'Default text\') { this.value = \'\'; }"` works, try this.

Comment: That was it, along with the fact that I didn't change "Default Text" to "Search". Thanks for your help man.